# Designing a haptic feedback motor vibrator circuit

Tags: transistors, dc-motor

I'm having a Vive Virtual Reality device which has one digital output pin.
Here is the specs for the digital output pin:
[image]

My plan is to use a 2N2222 transistor connected to that digital output, with a reverse diode parallel to the vibrator motor to protect for reverse back current from the motor inductance.

Is it sufficent ? is there any other alternatives circuit diagram that would work ?
I plan also to connect several motors, is one transistor like 2N2222 enough for driving 3 motors, which one motor consumes 300mA at peak, motor voltage 12V ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to use an n-channel MOSFET such as [AO3400A](http://www.aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AO3400A.pdf). No base resistor required and it will easily handle the 900mA peak with 3.3V drive. You still need the diode across the motor, of course.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you had had a look at the 2N2222 datasheet  you'd have seen that it says I_Cmax = 800mA, therefore it is not sufficient for 3 motors (3*300mA=900mA).
Also don't forget a resistor at the base, probably 220 Ohms.
The rest should be OK.